# Convert IQueryable List to Generic List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I am trying to call `GetScanningLogOnSettings()`, which queries the `ScanningDepartments` table to get the departments, then creates an instance of `ApplicationLogOnModel`, assigns the queried results to a variable within the `ApplicationLogOnModel`, and returns the result.

```
private ApplicationLogOnModel GetScanningLogOnSettings()
   {
       var mesEntity = new MESEntities();
       var departments = from dept in mesEntity.ScanningDepartments
                         select dept.Department.ToList();

       ApplicationLogOnModel depts = new ApplicationLogOnModel()
       {
           Department = departments
       };

       return depts;
   }
```

It gives me:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.List<char>>` to
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.Department>'`

Tried converting to lists and am having a little trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing some parentheses:

```
var departments = (from dept in mesEntity.ScanningDepartments
                   select dept.Department).ToList();
```

Your code calls `ToList()` on `dept.Department` and not on the whole query.

Comment: It is now saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.Department>.

Comment: @MarkSaluta: That's another problem and not the scope of this question. Most likely, `dept.Department` returns a string and `ApplicationLogOnModel.Department` is not a list of strings but of `Models.Department` instances.